# SSH tunneling to remote access MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, blackboard

I am trying to write Java program to access a remote mySQL database using ssh tunneling.

Below is my code:

```
int lport = 5656;

int rport = 3306;

String rhost = "111.222.333.444";

String host = "111.222.333.444";

String user = "username";

String password = "password1234";

String dbUser = "mySQLuser";

String dbPass = "mySQLpassword1234";

String schema = "test_db";





Connection conn = null;


try {


Properties config = new Properties();

config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");


JSch jsch = new JSch();

jschSession = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

jschSession.setPassword(password);

jschSession.setConfig(config);

jschSession.connect();

logger.info("Connected");


int assigned_port = jschSession.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);

logger.info("localhost:" + assigned_port + " -> " + rhost + ":" + rport);

logger.info("Port Forwarded");




Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/" + schema;

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPass);

logger.info("Database connection established");


Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


String sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


while(rs.next()) {

logger.info(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));

}


rs.close();

stmt.close();


logger.info("DONE");


} catch (Exception e) {

e.printStackTrace();

logger.error(e.getMessage());

if (jschSession != null && jschSession.isConnected()) {

System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection during error");

logger.error("Closing SSH Connection during error");

jschSession.disconnect();

}


} finally {

if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {

System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");

logger.info("Closing Database Connection");

conn.close();

}


if (jschSession != null && jschSession.isConnected()) {

System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");

logger.info("Closing SSH Connection");

//jschSession.disconnect();

}


}
```

I am pretty sure that all the usernames and passwords are correct.

However, when I am trying to run the above code, it always fail in the following line:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPass);
```

with the following exception:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 | java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'mySQLuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at com.prject.testing.Test.<init>(Test.java:97)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:995)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:477)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/02/20 17:25:24 |       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
```

I have also checked the mySQL, the "host" for the user "mySQLuser" has already set as "%" in the "User" table.
Could anyone give me some suggestions?

**Update:**

Adopting the suggestion from @bmorris591,

I have changed String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/" + schema; into String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + lport + "/" + schema;

However, there is a new exception appear:

```
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1044)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.project.testing.Test.<init>(Test.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:995)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:477)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:514)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:455)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
```

and still the error happened in this line of code:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, dbPass);
```

The error messages make me quite confuse,

Could any give me some more suggestions?

Comment: The implication is that the ssh tunnel is not working correctly. Try adding code to see if that works before adding the database connection.

Comment: Slightly off-topic question, but why do you need a java program to establish the SSH tunnel, wouldn't just using plain ssh to establish the tunnel be simpler, then your java program can just access the local port?

Comment: @Hei I have same problem to connect Java applications with SSH/SSL over TCP/IP connection. So, I found this link [http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/12/connect-amazon-ec2-instance-using-java.html] that uses certificate PEM - Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM). Do you have any idea about the solution for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to be that the error is on this line:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/" + schema;
```

Given than `rport` is `3306`, i.e. the mySQL port on the remote machine, you are connecting to

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + schema;
```

Which is your local machine. You need to connect to:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + lport + "/" + schema;
```

Which would be the port on the local machine that forwards to `3306` on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have changed to lport, now I have a new exception:
java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

It makes me a bit confuse......

Comment: It that case your tunnel isn't open I guess. If you do the `LocalForward` from your java application you should be able to test the tunnel from the command line.

Comment: So how would you commend on the Java code to do the tunneling,
as I originally follow this tutorial but seems it is not success in my case.
http://www.journaldev.com/235/java-program-to-connect-to-remote-database-through-ssh-using-port-forwarding

Comment: I would test the tunnel - for example remove the mySQL stuff from the code and add an infinite loop, then run the code and try and connect to the remote mySQL from the commandline using a terminal. This way you can debug the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

`"mySQLuser"@"%"` let's you connect from any *remote* host. You should have `"mySQLuser"@"localhost"` to be able to log in locally, which is the case when tunneling via SSH.

A default MySQL installation has an anonymous-user account with host of `localhost`, so when logging in locally, that is considered a more "specific" user. That is, without `"mySQLuser"@"localhost"` account, you are considered as the anonymous-user account.