# Connect to MySQL over SSH using Java

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, amazon-ec2

I want to connect to MySQL database on Amazon EC2 server using Java. I am able to create ssh tunnel using Jsch library and forward ports to that server, however connecting to DB always ends with exception

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

I think i am stuck in the same situation as Hei ([SSH tunneling to remote access MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976504/ssh-tunneling-to-remote-access-mysql-database))

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SQLException {
            final int lport = 3306;
            final String host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
             final String rhost = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
             final int rport = 3306;
            final String user = "user";
            final String dbuserName = "user";
             final String dbpassword = "password";
            final String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport  + "/information_schema?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
             final String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
             Session session = null;

            try {
                //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
                final java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                final JSch jsch = new JSch();
                session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
                jsch.addIdentity("path\\to\\pemfile.pem");
                session.setConfig(config);
                session.connect();
                System.out.println("Connected");
                final int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
                System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + rhost + ":" + rport);
                System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

                //mysql database connectivity
                Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
                dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);

                System.out.println("Database connection established");
                System.out.println("DONE");

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (dbConn != null && !dbConn.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
                    dbConn.close();
                }
                if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
                    session.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem using AppFog (in front of AWS). The only way I could workaround this issue was dropping the following from my connection string:

```
"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Off course, you should be sure that this will not affect your application requirements.