# Spark Scala - Connect to MySQL over SSH using Key Pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, spark-notebook

I wanted to understand if there is a method one can connect to MySQL database over SSH using Private-Public Key pair using Spark notebook for scala?

I have been trying to modify this code to no avail

[Connect to MySQL over SSH using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307825/connect-to-mysql-over-ssh-using-java)

Comment: Why is this tagged [apache-spark]?

Comment: Question is to specifically use spark .

Comment: Spark wraps JDBC connection and does additional validations. Some functions of JDBC connection may not work for Spark case. For example, comments in MySQL queries.